# How not to print, but send signal to the printer using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, printing

I'd Like to send print request to the printer so it processes the job and send it away without printing it at all. Did I make myself clear? :)

I would like to do it using PowerShell, The below command wastes paper:

```
"" | Out-Printer -Name "EPSON TM-T20 Receipt"
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by  doing this? i ask because it SOUNDS like a classic sidetrack from the real problem in question.

Comment: Your printer should understand [ESC/POS](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=72) so you could send an _almost dummy_ signal like _Beep the buzzer_?